# Vega Lite - Animated bar charts without looping PART2 (actually VEGA)

Tags: json, powerbi, powerbi-desktop, vega, deneb

I've almost found a workaround that achieves the desired result. However, there's one thing I'm still struggling to resolve — it might not be too difficult, but I'm getting used to Vega, which is a bit different from Vega Lite.

Currently, the bars grow from 0 to 4000, using a hard-coded value that should be replaced with the dynamic value corresponding to each bar.

Below is the signal that needs to be modified to dynamically store the corresponding value of each bar instead of using hard-coded value (lines 5-8 in the code):

```
{
"name": "ceiling_value",
"value": 4000
}
```

Afterwards the signal is passed to the clamp function which determines the minimum and maximum range of the bar:

```
{          
"type": "formula",
"as": "value",
"expr": "clamp(datum['zero_measure'] + increment, 0, ceiling_value)"
}
```

Complete code:

```
{
  "width": 200,
  "height": 220,
  "signals": [
    {
      "name": "ceiling_value",
      "value": 4000
    },
    {
      "name": "increment",
      "value": 1,
      "on": [
        {
          "events": "timer{70}",
          "update": "increment + 500"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "table",
      "values": [
        {"day": "1", "value": 2200,"zero_measure": 0},
        {"day": "2", "value": 3200,"zero_measure": 0},
        {"day": "3", "value": 1800,"zero_measure": 0},
        {"day": "4", "value": -1500,"zero_measure": 0},
        {"day": "5", "value": 700,"zero_measure": 0}
      ],

      "transform": [
        {
          "type": "formula",
          "as": "day",
          "expr": "datum['day']"
        },
        {
          "type": "formula",
          "as": "value",
          "expr": "clamp(datum['zero_measure'] + increment, 0, ceiling_value)"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "scales": [
    {
      "name": "xscale",
      "type": "band",
      "domain": {
        "data": "table",
        "field": "day"
      },
      "range": "width"
    },
    {
      "name": "yscale",
      "type": "linear",
      "domain": [0, 6000],
      "range": "height"
    }
  ],
  "axes": [
    {
      "orient": "left",
      "scale": "yscale"
    },
    {
      "orient": "bottom",
      "scale": "xscale"
    }
  ],
  "marks": [
    {
      "type": "rect",
      "from": {"data": "table"},
      "encode": {
        "enter": {
          "x": {
            "scale": "xscale",
            "field": "day"
          },
          "width": {
            "scale": "xscale",
            "band": 0.8,
            "offset": -1
          },
          "fill": {
            "value": "steelblue"
          },
          "cornerRadius": {"value": 4}
        },
        "update": {
          "y": {
            "scale": "yscale",
            "field": "value"
          },
          "y2": {
            "scale": "yscale",
            "value": 0
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Could anyone help please?
Thanks a lot! (Namely thanks to Davide who is always willing to help :) )

Comment: Can  you supply sample data or a .pbix?

Comment: I updated the code in the post with sample data. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to adapt this.

[image]

```
{
  "width": 200,
  "height": 220,
  "signals": [
    
    {
      "name": "increment",
      "value": 1,
      "on": [{"events": "timer{70}", "update": "increment + 500"}]
    }
  ],
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "table",
      "values": [
        {"day": "1", "value": 2200, "zero_measure": 0},
        {"day": "2", "value": 3200, "zero_measure": 0},
        {"day": "3", "value": 1800, "zero_measure": 0},
        {"day": "4", "value": 1500, "zero_measure": 0},
        {"day": "5", "value": 700, "zero_measure": 0}
      ],
      "transform": [
        {"type": "formula", "as": "day", "expr": "datum['day']"}
          ]
    }
  ],
  "scales": [
    {
      "name": "xscale",
      "type": "band",
      "domain": {"data": "table", "field": "day"},
      "range": "width"
    },
    {"name": "yscale", "type": "linear", "domain": [0, 6000], "range": "height"}
  ],
  "axes": [
    {"orient": "left", "scale": "yscale"},
    {"orient": "bottom", "scale": "xscale"}
  ],
  "marks": [
    {
      "type": "rect",
      "from": {"data": "table"},
      "encode": {
        "enter": {
          "x": {"scale": "xscale", "field": "day"},
          "width": {"scale": "xscale", "band": 0.8, "offset": -1},
          "fill": {"value": "steelblue"},
          "cornerRadius": {"value": 4}
        },
        "update": {
          "y": {"scale": "yscale", "value": 0},
          "y2": {"signal": "increment<=datum.value? scale('yscale',increment):scale('yscale',datum.value)"}
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: oh lovely, it works! so you just moved the condition into "y2"...I will have also negative value bars which do not animate with this but I guess when I put the condition into "y2" it should be fixed...
thanks a lot again sir!